# Will Visual Studio 2012 run on Windows 7 starter?

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2012

I cannot find anywhere, that it specifically says it will or won't.

Comment: try to check http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compatibility

Comment: I'd also try giving the express edition a go on W7S. If Express edition works, that's a decent sign the full one will.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course - Visual Studio doesn't care about the Windows edition.
But I've installed VS 2012 on an ultra silm netbook ( Processor brand Intel Atom, 2Gb RAM), and it's impossible to use because it's too slow.

Answer (score -1):

**No** , Because VS 2012 Is Used To Make Metro Apps (Apps For Windows 8) . You Can Not Use It On Any Edition Of Windows 7 . You Can Download *Visual Studio(VS) 2010* .